# Getting No value of location?

Tags: android, json, facebook-graph-api, null

Iam getting all the friends information like name,location etc as a graph object in response but when i want to get location from json it givea me no value of location..Please help me and tell me where iam doing wrong?

```
    Bundle required = new Bundle();
                required.putString("fields", "id,name,picture,location,locale,gender,email");
                Request req = new Request(session, "me/friends", required,HttpMethod.GET,
                        new Callback() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(Response response){
                               GraphObject is=response.getGraphObject();  
                                // Log.w("FriendsList", is.toString());
                               String location="";
                                      if (is != null) {
                                          JSONObject jsonObject = is.getInnerJSONObject();

                                          try {

                                              JSONArray myfriendlist=new JSONArray();
                                           JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                                           for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                                               JSONObject object = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
                                               JSONObject friendlist = new JSONObject();
                                                 JSONObject keyfriendlist = new JSONObject();

                                          JSONArray loc = jsonObject.getJSONArray("location");
                                          for(int j=0;j<loc.length();j++){
                                         location=object.get("id").toString();
                                          if(location==null||location==""||location=="null")
                                          {
                                              continue;
                                          }}
```

LOGCAT

```
04-18 18:48:37.360: W/System.err(28862): org.json.JSONException: No value for location
04-18 18:48:37.365: W/System.err(28862):    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
04-18 18:48:37.365: W/System.err(28862):    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:544)
04-18 18:48:37.365: W/System.err(28862):    at com.example.socialize_us.MainFragment$2.onCompleted(MainFragment.java:106)
04-18 18:48:37.365: W/System.err(28862):    at com.facebook.Request$4.run(Request.java:1240)
04-18 18:48:37.365: W/System.err(28862):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-18 18:48:37.365: W/System.err(28862):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-18 18:48:37.365: W/System.err(28862):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-18 18:48:37.365: W/System.err(28862):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4666)
04-18 18:48:37.365: W/System.err(28862):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 18:48:37.366: W/System.err(28862):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
```

Comment: could you please update the question with what permissions you are getting from facebook?

Comment: could you please update your question with a sample response which u get from Facebook after removing personal information?

Comment: location is a JSONObject not an JSONArray.

Answer (score 0):

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for location
```

This Exception tell json could not find  `location` TAG

Please make sure your `JSON` string have Array which conatined by `location` TAG

```
 JSONArray loc = jsonObject.getJSONArray("location")
```

Answer (score 0):

The graph API for "me/friends" only returns Friend's Name and fbid. But you are trying to read their other properties as well which will not be available in this call. 
This will return something like:

`{
      "name": "Friend's NAme", 
      "id": "545981122"
    },`

Check this here [Facebook Graph Api for me/friends](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/friends)

For getting one friend's locations you need to get his id from the above call and then get that single friend's details like :

> me/friends/545981122

Where 545981122 is the friend's id.

Hope it helps.

Cheers !

Comment: @Saad: When you want to see details of a single user you can make a graph API call like: `https://graph.facebook.com/570074679` where `570074679` is the fbid.

and it will return you something like: 
`{
  "id": "570074679", 
  "name": "Tahir Mehmood", 
  "first_name": "Tahir", 
  "last_name": "Mehmood", 
  "link": "http://www.facebook.com/eng.tahir.mehmood", 
  "username": "eng.tahir.mehmood", 
  "hometown": {
    "id": "110713778953693", 
    "name": "Karachi, Pakistan"
  }, 
  "location": {
    "id": "110713778953693", 
    "name": "Karachi, Pakistan"
  }`

You can see location here.

Comment: @ Tahir Mehmood yeah iam getting this but how to get this location": { "id": "110713778953693", "name": "Karachi, Pakistan" } iam getting no value of location